# Blazor - How do I binding a deeply nested child component to a variable on my page?

Tags: blazor, blazorise

I'm using a 3rd party autocomplete component in my app, and because I'm using autocomplete in several instances all with the same appearance and behaviour, I wanted to wrap it in my own component so I can do most of the plumbing once.

I'm trying to bind a property of the autocomplete component to a property of my wrapping component, which is then bound to a property of my page.

So 99% of the setup is done in the wrapper, all I need to do is create a function on my page to execute a search and set a propert which the wrapper is then bound to. My problem is (shown below) in the ReadData function (AutocompleteSearch).  If I set items to a static list the dropdown displays fine. If I invoke a function on my page, specified by the OnSearch property of my wrapper, the autocomplete does not appear. I think this must have something to do with binding in Blazor that I do not understand...

Here is my component wrapper:

```
@typeparam TKey

<Blazorise.Components.Autocomplete 
        TItem="AutocompleteItem<TKey>" 
        TValue=TKey
        Data="@Items"
        ReadData="@AutocompleteSearch"
        TextField="@((item) => item.Display)"
        ValueField="@(( item ) => item.ID)"
        Placeholder="@Placeholder"
        Debounce="true"
        DebounceInterval="100"
        FreeTyping="false"
        @bind-SelectedValue="SelectedID"
        @bind-SelectedText="SelectedText">
        <ItemContent>
            @if (context.Item.FrequentlyUsed)
            {
                <span class="@FrequentlyUsedClass">&nbsp;</span>
            }
            @context.Text
        </ItemContent>
</Blazorise.Components.Autocomplete> 

@code {
    [Inject]
    public ILogger<Blazorise.Components.Autocomplete<TKey, AutocompleteItem<TKey>>> Logger { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Placeholder { get; set; } = "Search...";

    [Parameter]
    public string FrequentlyUsedClass { get; set; } = "text-warning icon-dashboard-star-full";

    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<AutocompleteItem<TKey>>? Items { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<AutocompleteReadDataEventArgs> OnSearch { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public TKey SelectedID { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string SelectedText { get; set; }

    private async Task AutocompleteSearch(AutocompleteReadDataEventArgs args)
    {
        Logger.LogTrace("Search start.");
        
        //does not work
        await OnSearch.InvokeAsync(args);
        StateHasChanged();

        //works
        //Items = new List<AutocompleteItem<TKey>>()
        //{
        //    new AutocompleteItem<TKey>()
        //    {
        //        Display = "test"
        //    }
        //};

        Logger.LogTrace($"Items found: {Items.Count()}");
        Logger.LogTrace("Search complete.");
    }

}
```

Here is the relevant parts on my page:

```
@code {
    [Inject]
    private IDAL DB { get; set; }

    //Autocomplete
    private IEnumerable<AutocompleteItem<int>>? AutocompleteItems { get; set; }
    private int AutoCompleteSelectedID { get; set; }
    private string? AutocompleteSelectedText { get; set; }

    private /*async Task*/ void AutocompleteSearch(AutocompleteReadDataEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!args.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            AutocompleteItems = DB.SearchSampleItems(args.SearchValue);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I also tried another approach.  Instead of trying to bind the AutocompleteItems property of my wrapper to a property on my page, then bind
the Data property of the Autocomplete control to the AutocompleteItems property of my wrapper, I tried returning the items in the search arguments.  I think it ends up being cleaner, but still has the same result.

```
private async Task AutocompleteSearch(AutocompleteReadDataEventArgs args)
{
    Logger.LogTrace($"Search start: {args.SearchValue}");

    //does not work
    var searchArgs = new AutocompleteSearchEventArgs(args.SearchValue, args.CancellationToken);
    await OnSearch.InvokeAsync(searchArgs);
    Items = searchArgs.ItemsFound.ToArray();
    StateHasChanged();

    //works
    //Items = new List<AutocompleteItem<TKey>>()
    //{
    //    new AutocompleteItem<TKey>()
    //    {
    //        Display = "test"
    //    }
    //};

    Logger.LogTrace($"Items found: {Items.Count()}");
    Logger.LogTrace("Search complete.");
}

public class AutocompleteSearchEventArgs
{
    public string SearchValue { get; private set; }

    public CancellationToken CancellationToken { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<AutocompleteItem<TKey>> ItemsFound { get; set; }

    public AutocompleteSearchEventArgs(string searchValue, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        CancellationToken = cancellationToken;
        earchValue = searchValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `AutocompleteItems = DB.SearchSampleItems(args.SearchValue);` really a synchronous code block?  You've commented out the async in the method which makes me suspicious.  My guess is that the component is rendering before `AutocompleteItems` is populated, which suggests an async issue.
`

Comment: Can you show how you're declaring your wrapper component in your main page.  What gets mapped to the Parameters?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis - yes, it is a synchronous code block.  I've tried tried it async and sync,  with the same results.